# Warning: Could not find Lua 5.3 in PATH - When Trying to Install Gumbo library with Luarocks

Tags: lua, add-on, luarocks, world-of-warcraft, gumbo

When writing `luarocks install gumbo`
In the location/directory of my luarocks file in cmd, I am getting the following error

```
Warning: Could not find Lua 5.3 in PATH.
Modules may not install with the correct configurations. You may want to specify the path prefix to your build of Lua 5.3 using --lua-dir
Installing https://luarocks.org/gumbo-0.5-1.src.rock

Error: Failed finding Lua library. You may need to configure LUA_LIBDIR.
```

I've added lua53.exe to the same directory, and added the file both to my user variables and system variables in control panel.

Not sure if worth mentioning, but when running lua53.exe and trying to use `luarocks install gumbo` from there,
the lua53 cmd-like window responds with `stdin:1: syntax error near 'install'`
I was hoping to do some web scraping with lua, and later on building a World of Warcraft addon that utilizes gumbo to show certain helpful information within the WoW client, but I can't seem to even get the most basic stuff to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up LuaRocks on [Windows](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows) is annoying and I'm not familiar with it myself. If you added both the LuaRocks and Lua 5.3 [Windows binaries](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html) (Executables and Includes) to your `Path` system variable:

- `luarocks path` prints the [commands](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Using-LuaRocks#Commandline_tools_and_the_system_path) for setting up the `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` system variables.
- The [config.lua](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Config-file-format) file tells you what your `variables.LUA_LIBDIR` value is. You can check it with `luarocks config`. For me that file would be in:
  `C:/Users/Ketho/AppData/Roaming/luarocks/config-5.3.lua`
  otherwise you can create an empty file there and put in this line to point it to wherever your Lua folder is:

```
variables.LUA_LIBDIR = "C:/lua-5.3.5_Win32_bin"
variables.LUA_INCDIR = "C:/lua-5.3.5_Win32_bin/include"
```

As for using gumbo to show information within WoW, the addon environment is sandboxed. Unless you meant you just want to get the data to hardcode into your addon.

Comment: After messing with system variables and creating luarocks config file, I "managed" getting the following error while executing ```luarocks install gumbo```
------------------------------------------->
```gumbo 0.5-1 depends on lua >= 5.1 (5.3-1 provided by VM)
mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o gumbo/parse.o -IC:/gcc-lua-install/lua/include gumbo/parse.c
'mingw32-gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Build error: Failed compiling object gumbo/parse.o```

Comment: Oh wait, so it's impossible to run gumbo commands within a WoW addon?!

Comment: You also need to install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), as in `mingw32-gcc.exe` should be in your PATH. Also yes you CANNOT run gumbo or whatever Lua module in WoW. There is no communication possible with the outside environment. Why would you even assume that'd be possible?

Comment: Honestly haven't thought of security and fair-play implications of it. Just had the idea to make a a shortcut for looking for hints on how to complete problematic quests from wowhead comment section, like just right click a quest from the quest log, and the top comments from WowHead will pop into chat. Could've save a lot of people a lot of time, if some kind of http communication was possible from within the WoW client

Comment: There is https://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info7017-LightHeaded.html for that. It makes sense you can't open a HTTP connection within a wow addon